# What will happen if I query data (programmatically) while bookkeeper working on the Quickbooks?

Tags: quickbooks

I want to know what exactly will happen when I query data(using php devkit or qbsdk) from quickbooks while bookkeepers are working on it.

The question looks pretty simple but I'm really concerning about the company file to be corrupted or not in this case.

Any opinions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your bookkeepers perspective - nothing will happen. They won't even know you're querying it.

From your perspective - you'll get some data back.

QuickBooks is a database just like any other database. You can query data from it, and it won't corrupt that data. It will just query it.